# Drawing a linked list as a tree

Tags: tikz-trees

I'd like to draw this as a TikZ:

```
  \
   \
    +---+---+
    | * | * |
    +/--+---\
    /        \
   1          +---+---+
              | * | * |
              +/--+---\
              /        \
             2          +---+---+
                        | * | * |
                        +/--+---+
                        /
                       3
```

I've tried various things to make an "empty rectangle with a dividing line, to no avail. . . .

Comment: use a node from `shapes.multipart` library

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphdrawing,
  shapes.multipart
}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{
  link/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    draw,
    /tikz/graphs/as={\nodepart{two} \footnotesize\texttt{*ptr}},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [tree layout] {
  head [draw, as=\emph{head}] -- {
     link1 [link] -- {
       1, 
       link2 [link] -- {
         2, 
         link3 [link] -- {
           3, 
           link4 [link]
         }
       }
     }
  }
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is great, and I've got it to work, but I do need the split left and right nodes---as in my ascii diagram. I was trying to hack http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tree/.

Comment: @147pm I updated the answer to match more closely what you want (hopefully).

Comment: Actually, I need the edge lines pointing to the number leaves to be directly under the first cell of the rectangle, not the second cell, otherwise the effect is lost. Also, when I removed the "*ptr" in the second cell, the edge lines went up into the rectangle. I need the lines to just touch the rectangles, not hike up into them. Sorry to make such demands, but I have no idea how to learn this on my own. Is there documentation somewhere? Being non-technical, I can't get much from man pages or reference dumps.